# Codeception, how to split yml file?

Tags: php, yaml, codeception

I want to include second yml file to my api.suite.yml. Can I do it somehow?

I have api.suite.yml looking like this

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
        -   REST:
                url:
                port: 80
                depends: PhpBrowser
                part: Json
        -   Db:
                dsn: 'mysql:host=<MY HOST>;dbname=<MY DBNAME>'
                user: '<MY USER>'
                password: '<MY PASSWORD>'
```

Everything works perfectly fine, but I want to move DB creds in separate yml file and add it into .gitignore.

How can I do this? I already spend 2 hours and can't find it in documentation.
There is a mention about extends: here https://codeception.com/docs/reference/Configuration#extends

I tried to use it but it not seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is not possible. YAML doesn't support something like "import" or "require".

What you can do: using variables in a separate env file.

For this you need `vlucas/phpdotenv`

```
    composer require vlucas/phpdotenv
```

Then add variables into your yaml file:

```yaml
# Api.suite.yml
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
        - REST:
                url:
                port: 80
                depends: PhpBrowser
                part: Json
        - Db:
                dsn: %DSN%
                user: %USERNAME%
                password: %PASSWORD%
```

Then you add these params in your `codeception.yml` which enables you to use environment variables and env-files to your project.

```yaml
# codeception.yml

params:
  - env
  - .env.local
```

Put your variables to your `.env.local` file and ignore it via `.gitignore`.

```
# .env.local
USERNAME=<username>
PASSWORD=<password>
DSN=<mysql-dsn>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately yml/yaml does not support this. but if you want to use some block of code several places in a same yaml file then you can consider something like below

```
namespace: Tests
support_namespace: Support

# Define an anchor for your WebDriver configuration
modules:
  enabled:
    - &modules
      WebDriver:
        url: 'https://awesomesite.com'
        browser: chrome
        port: 9515
        window_size: 1920x1080
        capabilities:
          unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
          acceptInsecureCerts: true
          chromeOptions:
            args:
              - "--headless"
              - "--disable-gpu"
              - "disable-infobars"

# Define your test suites
suites:
  TestFolder1:
    actor: AcceptanceTester
    path: TestFolder1
    # Include the WebDriver configuration using an alias
    <<: *modules
    some_other_config_option: value

   TestFolder2:
   actor: AcceptanceTester
   path: TestFolder2
   # Include the WebDriver configuration using an alias
   <<: *modules
   some_other_config_option: value



paths:
  tests: tests
  output: tests/_output
  data: tests/Support/Data
  support: tests/Support
  envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
  enabled:
    - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
```

As you can see i made an alias of `modules` with `- &modules` and used the value with `<<: *modules`. This alias technique can reduce your code.  I don't know if you were looking for something like this or not. anyway thank you